# How to increase page load (Laravel 5 + Vuejs + Browserify)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, browserify, vue.js

I've done an app using Laravel 5.2, Vuejs, Browserify and Vueify but now I realised that my app is taking more than 6 sec to open! I took screenshots from my TIMELINE (chrome dev tools)... Anybody have any idea how can I make it faster? Or any advice/article that can help me?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

Comment: So it seems to me that you may have taken an Application that should've been Multi-page, and instead created a Single-page application. `72.3` mb JS heap!? that's HUGE.

Comment: Have you made any progress on that?

Comment: Not yet :/... I am still fighting it!

Comment: You can load the basics so the page will render, then do ajax calls for the rest of it, even show a loading screen meanwhile. In scripting group are all vue stuff?